# What field of mathematics is this? Necessary and sufficient corridors for topological routing

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, computational-topology

I am a computer scientist working on a problem in electronics design. The overall problem is about how to route traces on a circuit board, and I am looking for help on one of the subproblems.

We currently have a way of formulating the problem as a constraint satisfaction problem, and an algorithm for solving these constraints. However, many of the constraints are redundant and unnecessary, and the solver is wasting time dealing with them. We are looking for a conservative test that can identify the redundant constraints.

[router.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dELEU62ExN24r50pzoBNsDZBq4Y41Zy3/view?usp=sharing)

I feel this is a bit beyond me at the moment, so I am looking to contract or hire an appropriate mathematician to help tackle this problem with me, but I'm not sure what field of mathematics this is. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can direct me to some reading/groups/people.

If anyone has any hints on how to attack this problem, I would also be very grateful, and would be more than thrilled to solve it myself.

Heading

Comment: Looks to me like you want a graph theorist.

Comment: This problem is pretty well-studied in the context of VLSI routing (i.e., laying out wires inside a computer chip, as opposed to your problem of laying out wires *between* computer chips); Googling "VLSI routing algorithm" may serve you well, and may (?) offer a more fruitful first step than limiting yourself to the particular model in your link.

Comment: PS: This may reflect my ignorance of cultural norms, but I don't think MathOverflow typically acts as a mechanism for finding consultants.  Maybe you could just list your company or organization on your profile page for interested parties to investigate further?

Comment: Thanks Bill for your advice. Perhaps I should reword my post. I feel that the problem is slightly beyond my abilities right now (thus the request for a consultant), but if someone has a paper or hints on how to attack it, I would be grateful for that as well.

Comment: I notice, @PatrickLi, that Nature just published a paper on some work on optimizing floorplanning (i.e., routing on chips).  If you'd like to discuss this more, feel free to reach out to me directly.  Here's the Nature paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03544-w